# Is there a way to weaponize a Battle Magic Tactics token?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

So there's this feat from *Monster Manual V* that I don't think any creature except the text's three hobgoblin casters have *ever* taken.<sup>1</sup> Here it is.

> #### Battle Magic Tactics
>
> Through intense training and impeccable timing, you and your allies learn to augment each other’s magical attacks when you focus your efforts on a single target.
>   **Prerequisites:** Spellcraft 6 ranks, arcane caster level 3rd.
>   **Benefit:** Each time you cast a spell that requires the target to make a saving throw, that target gains a Battle Magic Tactics token after the spell resolves. A creature gains a token whether the save succeeds or fails, but a creature that avoids a spell through spell resistance does not gain a token. Each Battle Magic Tactics token imposes a cumulative −1 penalty on saving throws against the spells of spellcasters that have this feat. At the end of each round, all Battle Magic Tactics tokens disappear. (84)

As a thought exercise, let's say the DM is an absurd literalist and reads the feat to mean that its benefit causes the affected creature, however briefly, *to gain physical possession of an actual object*.<sup>2</sup>

Here's the question: Is there a class or creature special ability, magic item, spell, or other effect or combination of effects that can somehow optimize or weaponize this token-granting ability? That is, if a physical token is actually gained by the affected creature, is there a way to harm, help, or hinder the affected creature based on the caster having given the creature this according-to-the-wacky-DM now-physical token?

---

<sup>**1**</sup> My apologizes if I've underestimated this feat's rarity, and kudos to you if you've had a PC who took this feat *and* it was somehow effective. I *can* imagine a group of low-level casters (kobold sorcerers, perhaps) taking this feat and focus-firing their spells on a high-level foe so that their spells will be effective. That's a good use of the feat, I guess. But I think I'd still just give 'em all the feat Spell Focus.
<sup>**2**</sup> Note that *I* know that the token the creature gains from the feat is *supposed* to be a metagame construct used solely for tracking the affected creature's saving throw penalty *not*, like, an actual, for-reals Chuck E. Cheese token that says *−1 penalty on saving throws* or whatever. You needn't convince me otherwise. So don't get hung up on that.

Comment: This is skirting "Code Golf" territory, which historically we have experienced issues with hosting. Is there standing for this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just a hypothetical, which the SE FAQ says is not a good kind of question. http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2):

Spellcasters could have some fun with this, I believe. It wouldn't be "optimal" but could be some vulgar displays of power, manipulation, and crowd controlling. The following list is some of the ways I could foresee my mischevious spellcasters in toying around with my enemeies:

- There is a spell that specifically mentions tokens, but it is a
  5<sup>th</sup> level [Wizard](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/sorcererWizard.htm#wizard) spell.

  **Refusal** (Spell Compendium, p. 171)

  > You create a special ward that prevents unauthorized spellcasters or creatures with spell-like abilities from entering an area.
  >
  > You can choose to designate a password or special condition (such as character race, alignment, **possession of a token**, or any other
  >   observable or detectable characteristic) by which spellcasting
  >   characters and creatures can enter the refusal-warded area.

  In this case, "Creatures Possessing Battle Magic Tactic Tokens Can't
  Enter Area X," albeit not a weaponizing effect would still be a
  debilitating effect.

  Finding a way to cast [Shrink Item](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/shrinkItem.htm) on the token could possibly
  even make the creature not even realize he has it, or it would be so
  small he would have to spend actions to make a [Search](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/search.htm) check to
  find it in order to rid himself of it.
- There is a spell that could turn the tokens into objects of desire
  and greed, and create more tokens for enemies to fight each other
  over, but its a 2<sup>nd</sup> [Bard](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/bard.htm)/3<sup>rd</sup> Wizard spell.

  **Miser's Envy** (Spell Compendium, p. 142)

  > When you cast this spell, you designate a target creature and specify an object, both of which must be within the spell’s range. If
  >   the target creature fails its saving throw, it becomes consumed by a
  >   powerful desire for the object
  >
  > Once the creature gains possession of the object, it protects the item greedily, attacking anyone who approaches within 30 feet or who
  >   otherwise appears to be trying to take the object away.

  And there is a -4 penalty against dragons for this spell. Dragons and
  dragonkin could all be fighting each other over each other's tokens -
  that are all debuffing them in the process. Imagine those pesky
  kobolds...
- Any other spell that could affect objects that could be debilitating; [Darkness](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/darkness.htm), [Silence](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/silence.htm), and etc. could be effective. Casting [Invisibility](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/invisibility.htm) on the token could be a hilarious way of the creature not finding the token to get rid of it.
- [Spell research](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/arcaneSpells.htm#arcaneMagicalWritings) into the opposite of [Shrink Item](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/shrinkItem.htm) could perhaps
  encumber the creature, especially if he has enough of the tokens in
  possession, or at least be such a sizeable nuisance he would have to
  waste actions dealing with them.